# How to suppress warning messages when loading a library?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a r script from the command line, but I get warning messages when packages are loaded:

```
C:\Temp>Rscript myscript.r param
Warning message:
package 'RODBC' was built under R version 3.0.1
Warning message:
package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 3.0.1
Warning message:
package 'reshape2' was built under R version 3.0.1
Warning message:
package 'lubridate' was built under R version 3.0.1
Warning message:
package 'scales' was built under R version 3.0.1
```

I' tried to use `suppressPackageStartupMessages`:

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(RODBC))
```

or `supressMessages`

```
suppressMessages(library(RODBC))
```

but these did not suppress these messages. How to get rid of these warnings?

Comment: If you want to get rid of messages the best solution would be to reinstall those packages. They won't work under R >= 3.0 anyway.

Comment: I could not try but `suppressWarnings(library(RODBC))` should work. But I suggest to follow @zero323's advice.

Comment: I think you need to update R. Apparently you use a version < 3.0.1.

Comment: Yes, I use version 3.0.0. But anyways, how can I suppress these messages, when upgrading is currently not possible?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

These are not messages but warnings. You can do:

```
suppressWarnings(library(RODBC))
```

or

```
suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library(RODBC)))
```

to suppress both types.

Answer (score 33):

I put this at the top of all my scripts and preface my library loads with it:

```
shhh <- suppressPackageStartupMessages # It's a library, so shhh!
```

Then you can load the library thusly:

```
shhh(library(tidyverse))
```

and rely on perfect silence.

Comment: "It's a library, so shhh!"  

Answer (score 1):

I use a vectorized version of that:

```
library <- function (...) {
   packages <- as.character(match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)[[2]])
   suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(lapply(packages, base::library, character.only = TRUE)))
   return(invisible())
}
```

Then you just call library as usual:

```
library(tidyverse, ggplot2)
```